# Using highchart to get a series of a series in a column chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, data-visualization

I am using the basic column chart example here:

[Highchart Example from JSFiddle via HC docs](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic)

This is fine for a single xAxis series but I need one with double grouping like so:

[image]

I have the following HC script code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            ['Jan', '2020'],
            ['Feb', '2020']
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [[49.9, 2020], [71.5, 2020]]

    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [[83.6, 2020], [78.8, 2020]]

    }]
});
```

I need to figure out a way to make this work. I can use other JS charting libraries if they would be easier as I'm investigating a bunch of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use the `grouped categories highcharts module` in this case.

Docs: https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: "column"
  },

  series: [{
    data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5]
  }, {
    data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5].reverse()
  }],
  xAxis: {
    categories: [{
      name: "2020",
      categories: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
    }, {
      name: "2021",
      categories: ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
    }]
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tzkq2hjp/